# Borrow error when I try to modify last element of a vector

Tags: rust, vector, lifetime

I am trying to modify a `Vec<i32>` by doing `thing[thing.len() - 1] = other_thing;`. I get an error telling me that I borrowed first a mutable reference, then an immutable one. I could not find a workaround. How to modify last element of a vector in rust.
Working example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a092f6778df0290de7cee1f2321bf175

Comment: Please include the full error from `cargo check`, as well as reproducible code.

Comment: The compiler suggests a workaround (try using a local...).

Comment: That line alone will not cause any problems for the borrow checker. It will cause a problem *in conjunction* with an immutable borrow still in scope. Without seeing that immutable borrow, we can't suggest an alternative. See [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't borrow the same variable as mutable and immutable at the same time.

When you are trying to get length of vector, this is where immutable borrowing happens and panics (because at the same time you are trying to change it's content, eg. mutable borrowing)

You can do it in multiple ways.
Let's assume you have a vector with 2 slices

```
let mut thing = vec![[1, 2], [3, 4]];
```

First, with calculating and getting last item from vector manually (as you did in your version)

```
let len = thing.len(); // immutable borrow use
thing[len - 1][1] = 20; // mutable borrow use
```

But more idiomatic way of doing this is to use methods provided by `slice/vec` and map over returned `Option`

To get the last item we can use [last_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last_mut) (which will return `Option`) and map on that `Option` to get last item of nested `slice`, and change it's value to `20`

```
// Set vector's last slice's value at index 1 to 20
thing.last_mut().map(|s| s[1] = 20);
// Set vector's last slice's last value to 20
// In our case this is the same as previous one
thing.last_mut().map(|s| s.last_mut().map(|i| *i = 20));

assert_eq!(vec![[1, 2], [3, 20]], thing);
```